# In android studio how to add manifest file, if manifest file deleted from android project

Tags: java, android-studio

when I worked on my university android project, by mistake I deleted my manifest file and I did not know how to re-create or undo this happening. My android version is 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on manifest directory (create if it's doesn't exist) -> New -> Other -> Android Manifest File